# SQL Find product with highest value for each category

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max

A sample of my table is as follows:

```
id name  category year value seller
 1 item1 cat1     2000 1     1
 2 item1 cat1     2000 5     2
 3 item2 cat1     2000 2     2
 4 item1 cat1     2001 3     2
 5 item2 cat1     2001 1     1
 6 item5 cat2     2000 1     1
 7 item6 cat2     2000 4     2
 8 item5 cat2     2001 1     1
 9 item6 cat2     2001 5     2
```

I want to find the item with the highest value for each category and year (seller id is irrelevant - it just represents that the same product is actually sold by a different seller for a different price).

So the desired result would be:

```
 2 item1 cat1 2000 5
 4 item1 cat1 2001 3
 7 item6 cat2 2000 4
 9 item6 cat2 2001 5
```

Also, how could I find the top 5 per category and year and what if 2 items are the highest valued for a certain category-year?

I tried the following query but it's not what I'm actually looking for:

```
SELECT id, name, category, year, max(value) as value
FROM product_value
GROUP BY category, year, name
ORDER BY category, year ASC
```

This one retrieves the highest value of a product for each category-year.

Therefore:

```
2 item1 cat1 2000 5 2
3 item2 cat1 2000 2 2
4 item1 cat1 2001 3 2
5 item2 cat1 2001 1 1
6 item5 cat2 2000 1 1
7 item6 cat2 2000 4 2
8 item5 cat2 2001 1 1
9 item6 cat2 2001 5 2
```

Comment: So why is id 5 included in the (desired) result?

Comment: oops it was a mistake

Comment: I dont see how it is same with "Retrieving the last record in each group" since I dont want to get the last record in each group, since my data is not sorted with the last having the maximum value...

Comment: It's identical...     SELECT x.* 
      FROM my_table x 
      JOIN  
         ( SELECT category
                , year
                , MAX(value) max_value 
             FROM my_table 
            GROUP  
               BY category
                , year
         ) y 
        ON y.category = x.category 
       AND y.year = x.year 
       AND y.max_value = x.value;... see

Comment: Damn, you are right, I just read Eric's answer there and it makes more sense...thanks